# How to format clicked button BackColor as yellow in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, button

Trying to have the background of a non-ActiveX button change to yellow if a cell's value is not empty or "".

Throwing

> error 424 object required

```
Sub Button37_Click()
    If Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Range("I16")) Then
        Button37.BackColor = 65535
    End If
    Range("GuarantorDetails ").Copy
End Sub
```

Comment: You are missing a destination in your `Range("GuarantorDetails ").Copy` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy

Comment: If you're using a form control button, you can't change the back color.

Comment: @BigBen This is a non-activex form control button sitting on a sheet that copies a range to clipboard to be pasted externally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure what you are trying can be done the way you tried it. Here is how I would do it:

```
Sub Button37_Click()

      If Not ActiveSheet.Range("I16") Is Nothing Then

        'I used the macro recorder here, just so that you can too. just copy paste what it gives you.
        With ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array("Rectangle 1")).ShapeRange.Fill
            .Visible = msoTrue
            .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorAccent4
            .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
            .ForeColor.Brightness = 0.400000006
            .Transparency = 0
            .Solid
        End With

    End If
      Range("GuarantorDetails").Copy
End Sub
```

Info: I dont think you can change the color of a normal button, use a shape instead.

I dont think IsEmpty() gives consistent (if any) results if used on a cell on a sheet.

The named range had a space in its name. At least for my version of excel, this is not permitted.

I created a rectangle and renamed it "Button 37".

Comment: worked like a charm. Yes, I realized now that non-active x button can not change its back color! Thank you again